# Запуск из "Выполнить"

Tags: python, python-3.x

В Windows 10 при запуске *myPr.py* из *cmd* открывается оконное приложение, которое корректно работает. Был создан файл *myPr.bat* cо следующим содержанием `@py.exe F:\myPath\myPr.py %*`. В переменных среды пользователя *myPath* указан, при запуске из "Выполнить" `myScript` на доли секунды показывается консоль и ничего не происходит. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Добавьте строку `pause` в батник, тогда консоль не будет закрыта

Comment: *В Windows 10 при запуске myPr.py из cmd открывается оконное приложение* И какой диск/каталог при этом текущий? установите его в батнике на старте: `@cd /d F:\myPath && @py.exe myPr.py`.

Comment: Akina, *myPath* есть в переменных среды пользователя, прописывать директорию излишество, а вот ```pause``` помог, но вот ```exit``` для закрытия консоли не помогает. Это минорно конечно, но хотелось бы знать как это делать, либо так и остается иметь открытое окно и консоль либо ничего?